# Make RFID Tag as a variable

Tags: serial, esp8266, rfid

I want to make RFID Tag as a variable, and push it to the web server. But I struggle to do the `Serial.read` function.

Any solutions?

Here is my code

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> 
#include <SPI.h> 
#include <MFRC522.h> 

/* wiring the MFRC522 to ESP8266 (ESP-12) 
SDA(SS) - D4 (GPIO2) 
SCK - D5 (GPIO14) (hw spi) 
MOSI - D7 (GPIO13) (hw spi) 
MISO - D6 (GPIO12) (hw spi)  
IRQ - 
GND - G 
RST - D3 (GPIO0) (FLASH) 
3.3V - 3V 
*/ 

#define RST_PIN D3 // RST-PIN für RC522 - RFID - SPI - Modul GPIO5 
#define SS_PIN D4 // SDA-PIN für RC522 - RFID - SPI - Modul GPIO4 

const char *ssid = "Keluarga"; // change according to your Network - 
cannot be longer than 32 characters! 
const char *pass = "batikpekalongan11"; // change according to your 
Network 

String a;

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Create MFRC522 instance 
WiFiServer server(80); 

void setup() { 
Serial.begin(115200); // Initialize serial communications 
delay(10); 
Serial.print(F("Booting....")); 

SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus 
mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 

WiFi.begin(ssid, pass); 

int retries = 0; 
while ((WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) && (retries < 10)) { 
retries++; 
delay(500); 
Serial.print("."); 
 } 
if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { 
Serial.println(F("WiFi connected")); 
} 

Serial.println(F("Ready!")); 
Serial.println(F("Scan for Card and print UID:")); 
Serial.print("IP address: "); 
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); 

// Start the server
server.begin();
Serial.println("Server started");
  } 

void loop() { 
 // Check if a client has connected
 WiFiClient client = server.available();
 if (!client) {
 return;
 }

 // Look for new cards 
   if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) { 
delay(50); 
return; 
} 
// Select one of the cards 
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) { 
delay(50); 
return; 
} 
// Show some details of the PICC (that is: the tag/card) 
  Serial.print(F("Card UID:")); 
  dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size); 
  a = Serial.readString();
  Serial.println("kakak");
  Serial.println(a); 

// Wait until the client sends some data
Serial.println("new client");
 while(!client.available()){
 delay(1);
 }

// Read the first line of the request
String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
Serial.println(request);
client.flush();

// Return the response
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
client.println("<html>");

client.print("Card UID:");
client.print(a);
client.println("</html>");
//delay(1);
//Serial.println("Client disonnected");
//Serial.println("");
}
```

Comment: I've add my code to the the questions. Thank you~

Comment: What you already have on the Serial.read ? I cannot see a line. And what you try to read?

Comment: What makes you think Serial.read() has anything at all to do with the card data?

Comment: I'm sorry if my code didn't look so good. I'm still a beginner in this. I'm trying to read the RFID tag. I thought with Serial.read(), I could read the serial data on serial monitor, from the tagged RFID Card and transform it into a variable. My purpose is to send the RFID tag data to the web server. ~Thankyou (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Reading from the serial port does not read back what you wrote to it. It looks like the data you want is in `mfrc522.uid.uidByte`, so try to get that into `a`. You'll need to format it - you might find clues in your `dump_byte_array` function.